# Vector Fields with related Jacobian matrices

Tags: lie-groups, vector-fields, jacobian

Given two smooth vector fields $X$ and $Y: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, where $X(x_1,x_2) = (X_1(x_1,x_2), X_2(x_1,x_2))$ and $Y(x_1,x_2) = (Y_1(x_1,x_2), Y2(x_1,x_2))$, with the Jacobian matrices J(X) and J(Y). Suppose $J(X) = J(Y)A$, where $A$ is a $2\times 2$ constant matrix,

\begin{equation}
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{\partial X_1}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial X_1}{\partial x_2}\\
\frac{\partial X_2}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial X_2}{\partial x_2}
\end{array}
\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{\partial Y_1}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial Y_1}{\partial x_2}\\
\frac{\partial Y_2}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial Y_2}{\partial x_2}
\end{array}
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a_{11} & a_{12}\\
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{array}\right).
\end{equation}
Is it possible to express the vector field $X$ solely in terms of $Y$ and $a_{ij}$?

Do the relations between the Jacobian matrices of X and Y have any significance or implications when the matrix A belongs to some Lie Group of Matrix?

Comment: Where did you meet it ? It seems to be a very unituitive equality, I don't thnik we can find a relation between $X$ and $Y$. If $J(X) = AJ(Y)$, then $X = AY + cste$ and if $J(X)(x) = J(Y)(Ax)A$, then $X = Y \circ A + cste$ but in your case, I don't see anything.